How do I schedule backups of an external PostgreSQL using Google Cloud Serverless?
We have a PostgreSQL cluster managed by DigitalOcean that we want to back up to Google Cloud Storage on a schedule. I'm planning on creating a Cloud Function that runs on a schedule.
Because our databases aren't stored on Google Cloud, I can't use this guide that Google has published. And since pg_dump has to be installed on the system to be available, that isn't an option in Cloud Functions either.
What options do I have? Is it possible to use something like psycopg2 in Python or pg in Node.js?

Please refer to this document . if it doesn't solve your issue, Can you please tell me where your postgre is running ?

Thank you for your comment, but I would like to avoid paying for a third party solution.

Can you please share where your PostgreSQL is running ?

It's running on DigitalOcean

Can you please have a look at the document1  and document2  ? The documents might help you to resolve your issue. Additionally, you can also refer to this stackoverflow issue of similar context.

You can use pg_dump from a docker container started on a scheduled Cloud Run job. While pg_dump snapshots are self-contained, simple and convenient to use, you might want to instead consider Point-In-Time Recovery - those would take one initial snapshot, and then only collect the delta, so you wouldn't have to backup the same data over and over again. It also allows you to restore to any state in between backups.

Thanks. Cloud Run might be a better option. We do have PITR as well (included in DigitalOcean's managed database), but only for the past 7 days. This will be a complement to that when shit really hits the fan.

@HannesHultergård Aside from the convenience if you simply feel more comfortable taking pg_dump snapshots, there's no benefit of that compared to setting up your own PITR with deltas flowing out to your GCP bucket. I'm not sure why exactly they have the 7-day limit, but once you set up your own, not only will you be free to restore to any point, but except for the base backup, it'll also be faster and more lightweight overall than full-sized dumps. It's just as secure, only a bit smarter and more flexible.

Alright, I will check that out instead. Something that might be an issue is that I don't have full access to the server where the database cluster is. So it's possible that I won't be able to do anything more than a logical backup using pg_dump. But that might be a question for the DigitalOcean support

DigitalOcean support just confirmed that pg_basebackup can not be used and that they don't support physical backups. Also, replication privileges can not be given to a user, unfortunately


since pg_dump has to be installed on the system to be available, that isn't an option in Cloud Functions either. What options do I have?


Cloud Run. While Cloud Functions are supposed to abstract the underlying platform away, Cloud Run lets you define both the function and the platform it'll wake up on. Both services make up what Google advertises as Cloud Serverless.
Cloud Compute, a tiny VM with a simple script on it, scheduled to wake up, run it, then go back to sleep. You can save that as a custom image and configure multiple small backup workers like that.

The latter would kind of emulate what Cloud Run is supposed to handle for you, but it might be more intuitive (that's pretty much how you'd do it at home or on-prem). Might also be a bit more cost-effective, since more "cloud-native" solutions like Cloud Run, typically come at a premium - similar to how a managed database usually costs a bit more than a VM rented from the same provider, hosting the exact same db, with the exact same resources (except provider's secret sauce they justify the premium with).
Still, a job that involves just waking up and piping pg_dump|gsutil cp for a few minutes should cost you little to nothing regardless of which one you pick. You might want to look into multithreaded pg_dump -j to speed things up at the cost of some more CPU, and gsutil -m for multithreaded upload.

Thank you for the answer. I ended up running the backup job on a Linux server that we already had running. However, I might switch to Cloud Run in the future to improve the reliability. Considering what I asked in the question, I'm going to mark this as the correct answer.
